Change the exported variable when running the project
extends Area2D (bullet.script)
@export var damage = 10
@export var speed = 300

func _process(delta):
    var direction = Vector2.RIGHT.rotated(rotation)
    position += direction * speed * delta

func _on_area_entered(area):
    queue_free()

I changed the damage value in the bullet_scene via the inspector after running the game, but it does not change the bullet damage of the newly created scene in world_scene. I needed the change to be saved.
player_script
var pos2 = $Node2D.get_child(right_hand)
var new_bullet = bullet_scene.instantiate()
new_bullet.position = pos2.global_position
new_bullet.rotation = global_rotation
get_tree().root.call_deferred("add_child",new_bullet)


You said:

changed the damage value in the bullet_scene via the inspector after
running the game

Key word being "after running the game",
Make sure you're changing the value in the Local scene tree not the Remote scene tree since changes in remote do not persist in the editor

If that doesn't work try restarting the game engine (oddly enough this solves most problems)
If that still doesn't work I'd recommend adding more details of your project & editor screen shots so it's easier to identify your problem

bullets are add chilld . It  be fixed after saving bullet scene
